# flutter:: Can a variable be used in another file?

Tags: flutter, dart

home.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late Directory? appDir;
  late List<String>? records;
```

record.dart

```
class Records extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> records;
  const Records({
    Key? key,
    required this.records,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RecordsState createState() => _RecordsState();
}
```

app.dart

```
class App extends GetView<AppController>{ 
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const PrimaryColor1 = const Color(0xFF708FF8);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
        body: Obx(() {
          switch(RouteName.values[controller.currentIndex.value]) {
            case RouteName.Home:
              return Home();
              break;

            case RouteName.Record:
              return Record(records: records);
```

I need to return `Record(records: records)` in app.dart. The variable records is in home.dart. Is there a way to use the variable records in app.dart?

+) I tried changing it as follows, but 'recordnull' was printed.

home.dart

```
class video_Body extends StatefulWidget {
  video_Body({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _video_Body createState() => _video_Body();
  int index;
  static List<String>? records;
}

class _video_Body extends State<video_Body> {
  List<String>? get record => video_Body.records;
```

app.dart

```
    if(video_Body.records == null) print('recordnull');
      return Record(records: video_Body.records);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with being in a separate file.  You'd have the same problem if all of your code were in a single file.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do what you want to do, here are the two simplest ones I could think of:

### 1. Store the variable somewhere else.

It is hard to explain how to do this because I have very little information about what the home page is doing to the list of records, but the general idea is declare the list of records on the `app.dart` file and pass the value of the list into the `Home` class.

To do this, you will probably have to declare some sort of callback for when the `Home` class wants to edit the list, I will give you an example:

In this example, we have a button widget that displays a number, and when you press the button it increases the value of the number, and we want to access the current value of the number.

First I will show you the equivalent of your problem:

Button:

```
class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
  ...
}
class _MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
 
  int value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: Text(value.toString()),
      onPressed: () => setState(() => value++),
    );
  }
}
```

Home:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        MyButton(), 
        Text(buttonText), // how do we access the button text?????
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

And now, with the solution:

Button:

```
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  MyButton({required this.value, required this.onChange});

  final void Function(int) onChange;
  final int value;  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: Text(value.toString()),
      onPressed: () => onChange(value +1),
    );
  }
}
```

Home:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  ...
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  int value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        MyButton(onChange: (v) => setState(() => value=v), value: value), 
        Text(value.toString()),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Of course, this solution may not work for you depending on the situation.

### 2. Use a static class

The idea here is to move the variable you want to access into a static class, first you need to make a class with a static variable you want to access:

```
class RecordsService {
  static List<String>? records;
}
```

Because it is static, you can access it from anywhere, so on home, make the following changes:

Before:

```
late List<String>? records;
```

After:

```
List<String>? get records => RecordService.records;
```

and to access the value on app:

```
return Record(records: RecordService.records);
```

Hopefully one of these solutions solves your use case.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried the second solution but I get the error 'null check operator used on a null value'. I think the record list is not delivered.

Comment: Could you show where you are getting that error? also are you using a static class or did you move the variable?

Comment: I have added additional notes below the post. Can you please check my post again?

Comment: Yes, sorry, but I am still having a hard time understanding where the error occurs, however I can think of two possibilities: 1. the error occurs because you have **yet** to assign `records`, if that is the case, then giving `records` a default value and making it non-nullable would fix it, or just adding null checks everywhere. The second possibility is that the static class is updating, but the widget is not rebuilding, [take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70190334/12638504) for possible answers on that front